# Load cookies data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, load

I have a code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var myPlayList = [];
```

and I want to load data into `myPlayList = [];` from cookies, can I use `myPlayList = [$.cookie("data"`

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve this with:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Where you can use $.cookie('key..') to access your cookie.

Comment: can you post a example over here?

Comment: All you need to do is, when saving, serialize the list. And when loading, deserialize it. Easiest way would probably be to serialize it to JSON.